# find one line in XML file and replace the next line with some other content using python

Tags: python, shell, search, replace

Using python I need to replace the line in XML file when the above line is matched.

```
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dmrfolder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
```

here I want to search for `dmrfolder` if it found then I need to replace the below `1.0` with `somevalue`.

I followed the below way but it doesn't worked for me.

```
with open('test.xml', 'r') as file :
            data = file.read()
            fnl = data.replace(line[1], str)
            with open('test.xml', 'w') as fw:
               fw.write(fnl)
               fw.close()
```

The Expected result will be

```
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>dmrfolder</artifactId>
    <version>somevalue</version>
```

Comment: take a look at lxml

Comment: XML is not a line-based format - you could remove all newlines from your snippet and it would be just as valid and contains _exactly_ the same informations. IOW: what you want to replace is not a "line", it's an element node (https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/basic-xml-concepts-1.html). And the answer is: use a proper XML parser (DOM or SAX, depending on your source XML size etc).

Comment: Try to use xmltodict. You can read a file, convert it to dict, change the value, and then rewrite de dict to a xml file: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202978/converting-xml-dict-xml-using-python

Comment: I'm new to python.. so if you can post an similar example code that will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/)'s `getnext()` to modify the value of the immediate sibling of each `artifactId` element in the following way:

```
import lxml.etree

xml = """
<xml>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>dmrfolder</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</xml>
"""

root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)
for e in root.findall("artifactId"):
    e.getnext().text = "somevalue"

print(lxml.etree.tostring(root, encoding="unicode"))
```

Result:

```
<xml>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>dmrfolder</artifactId>
  <version>somevalue</version>
</xml>
```

Comment: Here I need to read the content from xml file as this xml file is very huge file

Answer (score 0):

If the data file format is exactly as posted (including the spacing), you can get by with [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

```
        fnl = data.replace('''dmrfolder</artifactId>
    <version>1.0''', '''dmrfolder</artifactId>
    <version>somevalue''')
```

For a variable or not well-known format, you can use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
        fnl = re.sub('(dmrfolder</artifactId>\s*<version>)1.0', r'\1somevalue', data)
```

- `\s` - any whitespace character, including `\n`
- `\1` - the 1st (here: the only) parenthesized group